# Загрузка дампа SQL средством php

Tags: php

```
$backupFile = 'table.sql';
$query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '$backupFile' INTO DATABASE table";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
```

Собственно сам код, но DATABASE такой команды не существует, как можно загрузить файл ДАМПА в базу table?

**и правильное решение данного вопроса**

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','gg'); // стандартное подключение к БД, у каждого свои параметры

    $sqlfile = 'gg.sql'; // файл который нужно загрузить
    if (!file_exists($sqlfile));
    $open_file = fopen ($sqlfile, "r");
    $buf = fread($open_file, filesize($sqlfile));
    fclose ($open_file);

    $a = 0;

    while ($b = strpos($buf,";",$a+1)){
    $i++;
    $a = substr($buf,$a+1,$b-$a);
    mysqli_query($conn,$a);
    $a = $b;
    }

    echo 'Загружено таблиц:'.$i;
и собственно вся процедура загрузки дампа базы данных в БД средствами php
```

Comment: @LLIAKAJI, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: нет мне не дан исчерпывающий ответ, потому пишу его сам

Answer (score 2):

Соединился с сервером, выбрал базу(если нет, то создал), отправил нужную команду(все из файла).
Файл расковырять любым удобным для вас методом(гуглится по, как вариант, запросу "работа с файлами php").

Для работы с файлами искать [тут](https://php.net/manual/ru/book.filesystem.php). file_get_contents() должно вам помочь.

Для работы с базой искать [тут](https://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php) или [тут](https://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php).

Comment: еще google.com напиши

Answer (score 1):

Шта?
Считывай файл и отправляй его на выполнение - вот и вся загрузка дампа :)

Comment: как это сделать средством php?

Comment: Ну... Любым удобным способом считываешь файл и скармливаешь всё `mysqli_query()`.  
P. S. Юзай `PDO` - куда удобнее на мой взгляд.

Comment: и каким образом загрузить его в базу? какие для этого есть команды, операторы и прочее?

Comment: Зачем?  
Дамп есть просто команды на SQL.  
Т.е. их нужно просто считать и выполнить.

Comment: ясно понятно, уже сам все решил